# How to merge customers from two of my android apps

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

my problem is that I have one version of my android application (lets say xx.xxx.xxx.versionA) and second one has same prefix (xx.xxx.xxx.versionB) but with different data. Both of them are  now free and stand-alone application.

My goal is to merge them to single application on Android market. Because I managed the problem of different data by in app download/purchase. So I want to make that people from 2nd application will be redirected to 1st one for updates (easier for maintance and so on).

Is it even possible? I can announce in app that they have to download 1st application for updates in future (even pop up the android page). But I want to be as much user friendly as possible with the merge.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most gentle way to do this would be to send users of version B a message saying that, current version they are using will be abandoned soon and they should install version A to keep using the application. Then a button click would take them to version A in the market so that they can install it.

You can do it with this code:

```
Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName);
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
startActivity(marketIntent);
```

where packageName would be package name of version A app.